# SpatialPointsDataFrame not showing on leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

This is probably very simple but my lack of understanding spatial data it is making me ask this question. Please give me a hint if you don't mind. My dataset is huge but I am only posting 75 records. I am trying to convert a dataframe with lat and long to spatial points and visualize with leaflet but for some reason my points are not showing. I believe I have the correct CRS. See below:

```
     fish <- structure(list(id = c("1007", "1007", "1007", "1007", "1007", 
"1007", "1007", "1007", "1007", "1007", "1007", "1007", "1007", 
"1007", "1007", "1007", "1007", "1007", "1007", "1007", "1007", 
"1009", "1009", "1009", "1009", "1009", "1009", "1009", "1009", 
"1009", "1009", "1009", "1009", "1009", "1009", "1009", "1009", 
"1009", "1009", "1009", "1009", "1009", "1014", "1014", "1014", 
"1014", "1014", "1014", "1014", "1014", "1014", "1014", "1014", 
"1014", "1014", "1014", "1014", "1014", "1014", "1014", "1014", 
"1014", "1014", "1041", "1041", "1041", "1041", "1041", "1041", 
"1041", "1041", "1041", "1041", "1041", "1041"), long = c(-1110643.625, 
-1111535.5, -1112427.375, -1113319.5, -1114211.75, -1115104, 
-1121059.375, -1127014, -1132967.875, -1138921.625, -1144874, 
-1143957.875, -1143041.75, -1142125.875, -1141210.125, -1140294.5, 
-1134365.875, -1128435.875, -1122505.875, -1116575.125, -1110643.625, 
-1447247.875, -1448402.125, -1449556.5, -1450711.125, -1451865.75, 
-1453020.625, -1458978.5, -1464934.75, -1470890.25, -1476844.625, 
-1482798.125, -1481619.625, -1480441.375, -1479263.125, -1478085, 
-1476907.125, -1470977.25, -1465046.5, -1459114.75, -1453182, 
-1447247.875, -1080974.875, -1081842.875, -1082711, -1083579.25, 
-1084447.625, -1085316.125, -1091275, -1097233.75, -1103191.25, 
-1109148, -1115104, -1114211.75, -1113319.5, -1112427.375, -1111535.5, 
-1110643.625, -1104711.375, -1098778.5, -1092844.875, -1086909.875, 
-1080974.875, -1542280.625, -1536336.875, -1530392.125, -1524446.25, 
-1518499.625, -1512551.875, -1513754.125, -1514956.625, -1516159.125, 
-1517361.75, -1518564.5, -1524535.875), lat = c(2534925.75, 2528988.25, 
2523050, 2517111.25, 2511171, 2505230.75, 2506127.75, 2507029.5, 
2507936, 2508847.5, 2509763.5, 2515700.25, 2521636.75, 2527572, 
2533506.5, 2539440.25, 2538528, 2537620.25, 2536717.25, 2535819, 
2534925.75, 2532156.25, 2526256.75, 2520356.75, 2514456, 2508554.5, 
2502652.25, 2503820.5, 2504993.5, 2506171, 2507353.5, 2508540.75, 
2514438, 2520334.75, 2526231, 2532126.5, 2538021.25, 2536838.75, 
2535661, 2534488, 2533319.75, 2532156.25, 2530530, 2524589, 2518647.25, 
2512705, 2506761.25, 2500817.5, 2501690.5, 2502568.5, 2503451, 
2504338.5, 2505230.75, 2511171, 2517111.25, 2523050, 2528988.25, 
2534925.75, 2534037, 2533153.25, 2532274, 2531399.5, 2530530, 
2520675.25, 2519440.25, 2518210.25, 2516984.75, 2515764.25, 2514548.25, 
2508654.5, 2502760.75, 2496866, 2490970.75, 2485075, 2486295.75
), order = c(241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 
249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 
260L, 261L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 
280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 290L, 
291L, 396L, 397L, 398L, 399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 
406L, 407L, 408L, 409L, 410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 
1081L, 1082L, 1083L, 1084L, 1085L, 1086L, 1087L, 1088L, 1089L, 
1090L, 1091L, 1092L), hole = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), piece = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    group = structure(c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 19L, 19L, 
    19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
    19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 
    49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L), .Label = c("1.1", "10.1", 
    "100.1", "1000.1", "1001.1", "1002.1", "1003.1", "1004.1", 
    "1005.1", "1006.1", "1007.1", "1008.1", "1009.1", "101.1", 
    "1010.1", "1011.1", "1012.1", "1013.1", "1014.1", "1015.1", 
    "1016.1", "1017.1", "1018.1", "1019.1", "102.1", "1020.1", 
    "1021.1", "1022.1", "1023.1", "1024.1", "1025.1", "1026.1", 
    "1027.1", "1028.1", "1029.1", "103.1", "1030.1", "1031.1", 
    "1032.1", "1033.1", "1034.1", "1035.1", "1036.1", "1037.1", 
    "1038.1", "1039.1", "104.1", "1040.1", "1041.1", "1042.1", 
    "1043.1", "1044.1", "1045.1", "1046.1", "1047.1", "1048.1", 
    "1049.1", "105.1", "1050.1", "1051.1", "1052.1", "1053.1", 
    "1054.1", "1055.1", "1056.1", "1057.1", "1058.1", "1059.1", 
    "106.1", "1060.1", "1061.1", "1062.1", "1063.1", "1064.1", 
    "1065.1", "1066.1", "1067.1", "1068.1", "1069.1", "107.1", 
    "107.2", "1070.1", "1071.1", "1072.1", "1073.1", "1074.1", 
    "1075.1", "1076.1", "1077.1", "1078.1", "1079.1", "108.1", 
    "1080.1", "1081.1", "1082.1", "1083.1", "1084.1", "1085.1", 
    "1086.1", "1087.1", "1088.1", "1089.1", "109.1", "1090.1", 
    "1091.1", "1092.1", "1093.1", "1094.1", "1095.1", "1096.1", 
    "1097.1", "1098.1", "1099.1", "11.1", "110.1", "1100.1", 
    "1101.1", "1102.1", "1103.1", "1104.1", "1105.1", "1106.1", 
    "1107.1", "1108.1", "1109.1", "111.1", "1110.1", "1111.1", 
    "1112.1", "1113.1", "1114.1", "1115.1", "1116.1", "1117.1", 
    "1118.1", "1119.1", "112.1", "1120.1", "1121.1", "1122.1", 
    "1123.1", "1124.1", "1125.1", "1126.1", "1127.1", "1128.1", 
    "1129.1", "113.1", "1130.1", "1131.1", "1132.1", "1133.1", 
    "1134.1", "1135.1", "1136.1", "1137.1", "1138.1", "1139.1", 
    "114.1", "1140.1", "1141.1", "1142.1", "1143.1", "1144.1", 
    "1145.1", "1146.1", "1147.1", "1148.1", "1149.1", "115.1", 
    "1150.1", "1151.1", "1152.1", "1153.1", "1154.1", "1155.1", 
    "1156.1", "1157.1", "1158.1", "1159.1", "116.1", "1160.1", 
    "1161.1", "1162.1", "1163.1", "1164.1", "1165.1", "1166.1", 
    "1167.1", "1168.1", "1169.1", "117.1", "1170.1", "1171.1", 
    "1172.1", "1173.1", "1174.1", "1175.1", "1176.1", "1177.1", 
    "1178.1", "1179.1", "118.1", "1180.1", "1181.1", "1182.1", 
    "1183.1", "1184.1", "1185.1", "1186.1", "1187.1", "1188.1", 
    "1189.1", "119.1", "1190.1", "1191.1", "1192.1", "1193.1", 
    "1194.1", "1195.1", "1196.1", "1197.1", "1198.1", "1199.1", 
    "12.1", "120.1", "1200.1", "1201.1", "1202.1", "1203.1", 
    "1204.1", "1205.1", "1206.1", "1207.1", "1208.1", "1209.1", 
    "121.1", "1210.1", "1211.1", "1212.1", "1213.1", "1214.1", 
    "1215.1", "1216.1", "1217.1", "1218.1", "1219.1", "122.1", 
    "1220.1", "1221.1", "1222.1", "1223.1", "1224.1", "1225.1", 
    "1226.1", "1227.1", "1228.1", "1229.1", "123.1", "1230.1", 
    "1231.1", "1232.1", "1233.1", "1234.1", "1235.1", "1236.1", 
    "1237.1", "1238.1", "1239.1", "124.1", "1240.1", "1241.1", 
    "1242.1", "1243.1", "1244.1", "1245.1", "1246.1", "1247.1", 
    "1248.1", "1249.1", "125.1", "1250.1", "1251.1", "1252.1", 
    "1253.1", "1254.1", "1255.1", "1256.1", "1257.1", "1258.1", 
    "1259.1", "126.1", "1260.1", "1261.1", "1262.1", "1263.1", 
    "1264.1", "1265.1", "1266.1", "1267.1", "1268.1", "1269.1", 
    "127.1", "1270.1", "1271.1", "1272.1", "1273.1", "1274.1", 
    "1275.1", "1276.1", "1277.1", "1278.1", "1279.1", "128.1", 
    "1280.1", "1281.1", "1282.1", "1283.1", "1284.1", "1285.1", 
    "1286.1", "1287.1", "1288.1", "1289.1", "129.1", "1290.1", 
    "1291.1", "1292.1", "1293.1", "1294.1", "1295.1", "1296.1", 
    "1297.1", "1298.1", "1299.1", "13.1", "130.1", "1300.1", 
    "1301.1", "1302.1", "1303.1", "1304.1", "1305.1", "1306.1", 
    "1307.1", "1308.1", "1309.1", "131.1", "1310.1", "1311.1", 
    "1312.1", "1313.1", "1314.1", "1315.1", "1316.1", "1317.1", 
    "1318.1", "1319.1", "132.1", "1320.1", "1321.1", "1322.1", 
    "1323.1", "1324.1", "1325.1", "1326.1", "1327.1", "1328.1", 
    "1329.1", "133.1", "1330.1", "1331.1", "1332.1", "1333.1", 
    "1334.1", "1335.1", "1336.1", "1337.1", "1338.1", "1339.1", 
    "134.1", "1340.1", "1341.1", "1342.1", "1343.1", "1344.1", 
    "1345.1", "1346.1", "1347.1", "1348.1", "1349.1", "135.1", 
    "1350.1", "1351.1", "1352.1", "1353.1", "1354.1", "1355.1", 
    "1356.1", "1357.1", "1358.1", "1359.1", "136.1", "1360.1", 
    "1361.1", "1362.1", "1363.1", "1364.1", "1365.1", "1366.1", 
    "1367.1", "1368.1", "1369.1", "137.1", "1370.1", "1371.1", 
    "1372.1", "1373.1", "1374.1", "1375.1", "1376.1", "1377.1", 
    "1378.1", "1379.1", "138.1", "1380.1", "1381.1", "1382.1", 
    "1383.1", "1384.1", "1385.1", "1386.1", "1387.1", "1388.1", 
    "1389.1", "139.1", "1390.1", "1391.1", "1392.1", "1393.1", 
    "1394.1", "1395.1", "1396.1", "1397.1", "1398.1", "1399.1", 
    "14.1", "140.1", "1400.1", "1401.1", "1402.1", "1403.1", 
    "1404.1", "1405.1", "1406.1", "1407.1", "1408.1", "1409.1", 
    "141.1", "1410.1", "1411.1", "1412.1", "1413.1", "1414.1", 
    "1415.1", "1416.1", "1417.1", "1418.1", "1419.1", "142.1", 
    "1420.1", "1421.1", "1422.1", "1423.1", "1424.1", "1425.1", 
    "1426.1", "1427.1", "1428.1", "1429.1", "143.1", "1430.1", 
    "1431.1", "1432.1", "1433.1", "1434.1", "1435.1", "1436.1", 
    "1437.1", "1438.1", "1439.1", "144.1", "1440.1", "1441.1", 
    "1442.1", "1443.1", "1444.1", "1445.1", "1446.1", "1447.1", 
    "1448.1", "1449.1", "145.1", "1450.1", "1451.1", "1452.1", 
    "1453.1", "1454.1", "1455.1", "1456.1", "1457.1", "1458.1", 
    "1459.1", "146.1", "1460.1", "1461.1", "1462.1", "1463.1", 
    "1464.1", "1465.1", "1466.1", "1467.1", "1468.1", "1469.1", 
    "147.1", "1470.1", "1471.1", "1472.1", "1473.1", "1474.1", 
    "1475.1", "1476.1", "1477.1", "1478.1", "1479.1", "148.1", 
    "1480.1", "1481.1", "1482.1", "1483.1", "1484.1", "1485.1", 
    "1486.1", "1487.1", "1488.1", "1489.1", "149.1", "1490.1", 
    "1491.1", "1492.1", "1493.1", "1494.1", "1495.1", "1496.1", 
    "1497.1", "1498.1", "1499.1", "15.1", "150.1", "1500.1", 
    "1501.1", "1502.1", "1503.1", "1504.1", "1505.1", "1506.1", 
    "1507.1", "1508.1", "1509.1", "151.1", "1510.1", "1511.1", 
    "1512.1", "1513.1", "1514.1", "1515.1", "1516.1", "1517.1", 
    "1518.1", "1519.1", "152.1", "1520.1", "1521.1", "1522.1", 
    "1523.1", "1524.1", "1525.1", "1526.1", "1527.1", "1528.1", 
    "1529.1", "153.1", "1530.1", "1531.1", "1532.1", "1533.1", 
    "1534.1", "1535.1", "1536.1", "1537.1", "1538.1", "1539.1", 
    "154.1", "1540.1", "1541.1", "1542.1", "1543.1", "1544.1", 
    "1545.1", "1546.1", "1547.1", "1548.1", "1549.1", "155.1", 
    "1550.1", "1551.1", "1552.1", "1553.1", "1554.1", "1555.1", 
    "1556.1", "1557.1", "1558.1", "1559.1", "156.1", "1560.1", 
    "1561.1", "1562.1", "1563.1", "1564.1", "1565.1", "1566.1", 
    "1567.1", "1568.1", "1569.1", "157.1", "1570.1", "1571.1", 
    "1572.1", "1573.1", "1574.1", "1575.1", "1576.1", "1577.1", 
    "1578.1", "1579.1", "158.1", "1580.1", "1581.1", "1582.1", 
    "1583.1", "1584.1", "1585.1", "1586.1", "1587.1", "1588.1", 
    "1589.1", "159.1", "1590.1", "1591.1", "16.1", "160.1", "161.1", 
    "162.1", "163.1", "164.1", "165.1", "166.1", "167.1", "168.1", 
    "169.1", "17.1", "170.1", "171.1", "172.1", "173.1", "174.1", 
    "175.1", "176.1", "177.1", "178.1", "179.1", "18.1", "180.1", 
    "181.1", "182.1", "183.1", "184.1", "185.1", "186.1", "187.1", 
    "188.1", "189.1", "19.1", "190.1", "191.1", "192.1", "193.1", 
    "194.1", "195.1", "196.1", "197.1", "198.1", "199.1", "2.1", 
    "20.1", "200.1", "201.1", "202.1", "203.1", "204.1", "205.1", 
    "206.1", "207.1", "208.1", "209.1", "21.1", "210.1", "211.1", 
    "212.1", "213.1", "214.1", "215.1", "216.1", "217.1", "218.1", 
    "219.1", "22.1", "220.1", "221.1", "222.1", "223.1", "224.1", 
    "225.1", "226.1", "227.1", "228.1", "229.1", "23.1", "230.1", 
    "231.1", "232.1", "233.1", "234.1", "235.1", "236.1", "237.1", 
    "238.1", "239.1", "24.1", "240.1", "241.1", "242.1", "243.1", 
    "244.1", "245.1", "246.1", "247.1", "248.1", "249.1", "25.1", 
    "250.1", "251.1", "252.1", "253.1", "254.1", "255.1", "256.1", 
    "257.1", "258.1", "259.1", "26.1", "260.1", "261.1", "262.1", 
    "263.1", "264.1", "265.1", "266.1", "267.1", "268.1", "269.1", 
    "27.1", "270.1", "271.1", "272.1", "273.1", "274.1", "275.1", 
    "276.1", "277.1", "278.1", "279.1", "28.1", "280.1", "281.1", 
    "282.1", "283.1", "284.1", "285.1", "286.1", "287.1", "288.1", 
    "289.1", "29.1", "290.1", "291.1", "292.1", "293.1", "294.1", 
    "295.1", "296.1", "297.1", "298.1", "299.1", "3.1", "30.1", 
    "300.1", "301.1", "302.1", "303.1", "304.1", "305.1", "306.1", 
    "307.1", "308.1", "309.1", "31.1", "310.1", "311.1", "312.1", 
    "313.1", "314.1", "315.1", "316.1", "317.1", "318.1", "319.1", 
    "32.1", "320.1", "321.1", "322.1", "323.1", "324.1", "325.1", 
    "326.1", "327.1", "328.1", "329.1", "33.1", "330.1", "331.1", 
    "332.1", "333.1", "334.1", "335.1", "336.1", "337.1", "338.1", 
    "339.1", "34.1", "340.1", "341.1", "342.1", "343.1", "344.1", 
    "345.1", "346.1", "347.1", "348.1", "349.1", "35.1", "350.1", 
    "351.1", "352.1", "353.1", "354.1", "355.1", "356.1", "357.1", 
    "358.1", "359.1", "36.1", "360.1", "361.1", "362.1", "363.1", 
    "364.1", "365.1", "366.1", "367.1", "368.1", "369.1", "37.1", 
    "370.1", "371.1", "372.1", "373.1", "374.1", "375.1", "376.1", 
    "377.1", "378.1", "379.1", "38.1", "380.1", "381.1", "382.1", 
    "383.1", "384.1", "385.1", "386.1", "387.1", "388.1", "389.1", 
    "39.1", "390.1", "391.1", "392.1", "393.1", "394.1", "395.1", 
    "396.1", "397.1", "398.1", "399.1", "4.1", "40.1", "400.1", 
    "401.1", "402.1", "403.1", "404.1", "405.1", "406.1", "407.1", 
    "408.1", "409.1", "41.1", "410.1", "411.1", "412.1", "413.1", 
    "414.1", "415.1", "416.1", "417.1", "418.1", "419.1", "42.1", 
    "420.1", "421.1", "422.1", "423.1", "424.1", "425.1", "426.1", 
    "427.1", "428.1", "429.1", "43.1", "430.1", "431.1", "432.1", 
    "433.1", "434.1", "435.1", "436.1", "437.1", "438.1", "439.1", 
    "44.1", "440.1", "441.1", "442.1", "443.1", "444.1", "445.1", 
    "446.1", "447.1", "448.1", "449.1", "45.1", "450.1", "451.1", 
    "452.1", "453.1", "454.1", "455.1", "456.1", "457.1", "458.1", 
    "459.1", "46.1", "460.1", "461.1", "462.1", "463.1", "464.1", 
    "465.1", "466.1", "467.1", "468.1", "469.1", "47.1", "470.1", 
    "471.1", "472.1", "473.1", "474.1", "475.1", "476.1", "477.1", 
    "478.1", "479.1", "48.1", "480.1", "481.1", "482.1", "483.1", 
    "484.1", "485.1", "486.1", "487.1", "488.1", "489.1", "49.1", 
    "490.1", "491.1", "492.1", "493.1", "494.1", "495.1", "496.1", 
    "497.1", "498.1", "499.1", "5.1", "50.1", "500.1", "501.1", 
    "502.1", "503.1", "504.1", "505.1", "506.1", "507.1", "508.1", 
    "509.1", "51.1", "510.1", "511.1", "512.1", "513.1", "514.1", 
    "515.1", "516.1", "517.1", "518.1", "519.1", "52.1", "520.1", 
    "521.1", "522.1", "523.1", "524.1", "525.1", "526.1", "527.1", 
    "528.1", "529.1", "53.1", "530.1", "531.1", "532.1", "533.1", 
    "534.1", "535.1", "536.1", "537.1", "538.1", "539.1", "54.1", 
    "540.1", "541.1", "542.1", "543.1", "544.1", "545.1", "546.1", 
    "547.1", "548.1", "549.1", "55.1", "550.1", "551.1", "552.1", 
    "553.1", "554.1", "555.1", "556.1", "557.1", "558.1", "559.1", 
    "56.1", "560.1", "561.1", "562.1", "563.1", "564.1", "565.1", 
    "566.1", "567.1", "568.1", "569.1", "57.1", "570.1", "571.1", 
    "572.1", "573.1", "574.1", "575.1", "576.1", "577.1", "578.1", 
    "579.1", "58.1", "580.1", "581.1", "582.1", "583.1", "584.1", 
    "585.1", "586.1", "587.1", "588.1", "589.1", "59.1", "590.1", 
    "591.1", "592.1", "593.1", "594.1", "595.1", "596.1", "597.1", 
    "598.1", "599.1", "6.1", "60.1", "600.1", "601.1", "602.1", 
    "603.1", "604.1", "605.1", "606.1", "607.1", "608.1", "609.1", 
    "61.1", "610.1", "611.1", "612.1", "613.1", "614.1", "615.1", 
    "616.1", "617.1", "618.1", "619.1", "62.1", "620.1", "621.1", 
    "622.1", "623.1", "624.1", "625.1", "626.1", "627.1", "628.1", 
    "629.1", "63.1", "630.1", "631.1", "632.1", "633.1", "634.1", 
    "635.1", "636.1", "637.1", "638.1", "639.1", "64.1", "640.1", 
    "641.1", "642.1", "643.1", "644.1", "645.1", "646.1", "647.1", 
    "648.1", "649.1", "65.1", "650.1", "651.1", "652.1", "653.1", 
    "654.1", "655.1", "656.1", "657.1", "658.1", "659.1", "66.1", 
    "660.1", "661.1", "662.1", "663.1", "664.1", "665.1", "666.1", 
    "667.1", "668.1", "669.1", "67.1", "670.1", "671.1", "672.1", 
    "673.1", "674.1", "675.1", "676.1", "677.1", "678.1", "679.1", 
    "68.1", "680.1", "681.1", "682.1", "683.1", "684.1", "685.1", 
    "686.1", "687.1", "688.1", "689.1", "69.1", "690.1", "691.1", 
    "692.1", "693.1", "694.1", "695.1", "696.1", "697.1", "698.1", 
    "699.1", "7.1", "70.1", "700.1", "701.1", "702.1", "703.1", 
    "704.1", "705.1", "706.1", "707.1", "708.1", "709.1", "71.1", 
    "710.1", "711.1", "712.1", "713.1", "714.1", "715.1", "716.1", 
    "717.1", "718.1", "719.1", "72.1", "720.1", "721.1", "722.1", 
    "723.1", "724.1", "725.1", "726.1", "727.1", "728.1", "729.1", 
    "73.1", "730.1", "731.1", "732.1", "733.1", "734.1", "735.1", 
    "736.1", "737.1", "738.1", "739.1", "74.1", "740.1", "741.1", 
    "742.1", "743.1", "744.1", "745.1", "746.1", "747.1", "748.1", 
    "749.1", "75.1", "750.1", "751.1", "752.1", "753.1", "754.1", 
    "755.1", "756.1", "757.1", "758.1", "759.1", "76.1", "760.1", 
    "761.1", "762.1", "763.1", "764.1", "765.1", "766.1", "767.1", 
    "768.1", "769.1", "77.1", "770.1", "771.1", "772.1", "773.1", 
    "774.1", "775.1", "776.1", "777.1", "778.1", "779.1", "78.1", 
    "780.1", "781.1", "782.1", "783.1", "784.1", "785.1", "786.1", 
    "787.1", "788.1", "789.1", "79.1", "790.1", "791.1", "792.1", 
    "793.1", "794.1", "795.1", "796.1", "797.1", "798.1", "799.1", 
    "8.1", "80.1", "800.1", "801.1", "802.1", "803.1", "804.1", 
    "805.1", "806.1", "807.1", "808.1", "809.1", "81.1", "810.1", 
    "811.1", "812.1", "813.1", "814.1", "815.1", "816.1", "817.1", 
    "818.1", "819.1", "82.1", "820.1", "821.1", "822.1", "823.1", 
    "824.1", "825.1", "826.1", "827.1", "828.1", "829.1", "83.1", 
    "830.1", "831.1", "832.1", "833.1", "834.1", "835.1", "836.1", 
    "837.1", "838.1", "839.1", "84.1", "840.1", "841.1", "842.1", 
    "843.1", "844.1", "845.1", "846.1", "847.1", "848.1", "849.1", 
    "85.1", "850.1", "851.1", "852.1", "853.1", "854.1", "855.1", 
    "856.1", "857.1", "858.1", "859.1", "86.1", "860.1", "861.1", 
    "862.1", "863.1", "864.1", "865.1", "866.1", "867.1", "868.1", 
    "869.1", "87.1", "870.1", "871.1", "872.1", "873.1", "874.1", 
    "875.1", "876.1", "877.1", "878.1", "879.1", "88.1", "880.1", 
    "881.1", "882.1", "883.1", "884.1", "885.1", "886.1", "887.1", 
    "888.1", "889.1", "89.1", "890.1", "891.1", "892.1", "893.1", 
    "894.1", "895.1", "896.1", "897.1", "898.1", "899.1", "9.1", 
    "90.1", "900.1", "901.1", "902.1", "903.1", "904.1", "905.1", 
    "906.1", "907.1", "908.1", "909.1", "91.1", "910.1", "911.1", 
    "912.1", "913.1", "914.1", "915.1", "916.1", "917.1", "918.1", 
    "919.1", "92.1", "920.1", "921.1", "922.1", "923.1", "924.1", 
    "925.1", "926.1", "927.1", "928.1", "929.1", "93.1", "930.1", 
    "931.1", "932.1", "933.1", "934.1", "935.1", "936.1", "937.1", 
    "938.1", "939.1", "94.1", "940.1", "941.1", "942.1", "943.1", 
    "944.1", "945.1", "946.1", "947.1", "948.1", "949.1", "95.1", 
    "950.1", "951.1", "952.1", "953.1", "954.1", "955.1", "956.1", 
    "957.1", "958.1", "959.1", "96.1", "960.1", "961.1", "962.1", 
    "963.1", "964.1", "965.1", "966.1", "967.1", "968.1", "969.1", 
    "97.1", "970.1", "971.1", "972.1", "973.1", "974.1", "975.1", 
    "976.1", "977.1", "978.1", "979.1", "98.1", "980.1", "981.1", 
    "982.1", "983.1", "984.1", "985.1", "986.1", "987.1", "988.1", 
    "989.1", "99.1", "990.1", "991.1", "992.1", "993.1", "994.1", 
    "995.1", "996.1", "997.1", "998.1", "999.1"), class = "factor"), 
    AREA = c(902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 
    902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 
    902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 
    902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 910740000, 910740000, 
    910740000, 910740000, 910740000, 910740000, 910740000, 910740000, 
    910740000, 910740000, 910740000, 910740000, 910740000, 910740000, 
    910740000, 910740000, 910740000, 910740000, 910740000, 910740000, 
    910740000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 
    902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 
    902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 
    902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 914860000, 914860000, 
    914860000, 914860000, 914860000, 914860000, 914860000, 914860000, 
    914860000, 914860000, 914860000, 914860000), PERIMETER = c(120161.852, 
    120161.852, 120161.852, 120161.852, 120161.852, 120161.852, 
    120161.852, 120161.852, 120161.852, 120161.852, 120161.852, 
    120161.852, 120161.852, 120161.852, 120161.852, 120161.852, 
    120161.852, 120161.852, 120161.852, 120161.852, 120161.852, 
    120714.531, 120714.531, 120714.531, 120714.531, 120714.531, 
    120714.531, 120714.531, 120714.531, 120714.531, 120714.531, 
    120714.531, 120714.531, 120714.531, 120714.531, 120714.531, 
    120714.531, 120714.531, 120714.531, 120714.531, 120714.531, 
    120714.531, 120161.773, 120161.773, 120161.773, 120161.773, 
    120161.773, 120161.773, 120161.773, 120161.773, 120161.773, 
    120161.773, 120161.773, 120161.773, 120161.773, 120161.773, 
    120161.773, 120161.773, 120161.773, 120161.773, 120161.773, 
    120161.773, 120161.773, 120988.43, 120988.43, 120988.43, 
    120988.43, 120988.43, 120988.43, 120988.43, 120988.43, 120988.43, 
    120988.43, 120988.43, 120988.43), MAJOR_LC = structure(c(6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("21", 
    "23", "31", "33", "41", "42", "43", "51", "71", "81", "82", 
    "83", "84"), class = "factor"), WOLVES_01 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), RD_DENSITY = c(0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 
    0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 
    0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 
    0.568, 0.568, 0.568, 0.568, 0.568, 0.568, 0.568, 0.568, 0.568, 
    0.568, 0.568, 0.568, 0.568, 0.568, 0.568, 0.568, 0.568, 0.568, 
    0.568, 0.568, 0.568, 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 
    0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 
    0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 0.204, 0.44, 0.44, 0.44, 
    0.44, 0.44, 0.44, 0.44, 0.44, 0.44, 0.44, 0.44, 0.44), WOLVES_99 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1", "2"), class = "factor"), PRED_SUIT = c(0.603, 0.603, 
    0.603, 0.603, 0.603, 0.603, 0.603, 0.603, 0.603, 0.603, 0.603, 
    0.603, 0.603, 0.603, 0.603, 0.603, 0.603, 0.603, 0.603, 0.603, 
    0.603, 0.555, 0.555, 0.555, 0.555, 0.555, 0.555, 0.555, 0.555, 
    0.555, 0.555, 0.555, 0.555, 0.555, 0.555, 0.555, 0.555, 0.555, 
    0.555, 0.555, 0.555, 0.555, 0.606, 0.606, 0.606, 0.606, 0.606, 
    0.606, 0.606, 0.606, 0.606, 0.606, 0.606, 0.606, 0.606, 0.606, 
    0.606, 0.606, 0.606, 0.606, 0.606, 0.606, 0.606, 0.574, 0.574, 
    0.574, 0.574, 0.574, 0.574, 0.574, 0.574, 0.574, 0.574, 0.574, 
    0.574)), row.names = c(241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 
247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 
258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 
278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 
289L, 290L, 291L, 396L, 397L, 398L, 399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 
404L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 408L, 409L, 410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 
415L, 416L, 1081L, 1082L, 1083L, 1084L, 1085L, 1086L, 1087L, 
1088L, 1089L, 1090L, 1091L, 1092L), class = "data.frame")


    # Convert fish dataframe to SpatialPointsDataFrame and use it with leaflet
    xy <- fish[,c(2,3)] 
      fish2 <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = xy, data = fish,
                                   proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 
     +no_defs"))

    leaflet() %>%  addTiles %>% addCircles(data = fish2,~ long,~ lat,color = "red",
    radius = 40,stroke = FALSE,fillOpacity = 0.9,group = "fish")  %>%
    addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("fish"),
    baseGroups = c("Esri.WorldImagery","OpenStreetMap"),position="topleft",
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, using a shorter example will make it easier to debug. Just with four points (not keeping the correct attributes), you see that the projection of the map does not match the coordinates. If I change the coordinates, your example seems to work:

```
library(sp)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
long_org <-c(-1110643.625,  -1111535.5, -1112427.375, -1113319.5)
lat_org <- c(2534925.75, 2528988.25, 2523050, 2517111.25)
d <- data.frame(lon=long_org, lat=lat_org)
coordinates(d) <- c("lon", "lat")
proj4string(d) <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84")
d_wgs84 <- spTransform(d, "+init=epsg:4326")

fish <- structure(list(
  id = c("1007", "1007",  "1009", "1009"),
  #long = c(-1110643.625,  -1111535.5, -1112427.375, -1113319.5),
  #lat = c(2534925.75, 2528988.25, 2523050, 2517111.25),
  long = coordinates(d_wgs84)[,"lon"],
  lat = coordinates(d_wgs84)[,"lat"],
  order = c(241L, 242L, 243L, 244L),
  hole = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), piece = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
  group = structure(c(11L, 11L,13L, 13L),
                    .Label = c("1.1", "10.1", "100.1", "1000.1"),
                    class = "factor"), 
  AREA = c(902430000, 902430000, 902430000, 902430000),
  PERIMETER = c(120161.852, 120161.852, 120161.852, 120161.852),
  MAJOR_LC = structure(c(6L, 6L,6L, 6L), .Label = c("21","23", "31", "33"), class = "factor"),
  WOLVES_01 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),
  RD_DENSITY = c(0.231, 0.231, 0.231, 0.231),
  WOLVES_99 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2"), class = "factor"),
  PRED_SUIT = c(0.603, 0.603, 0.603, 0.603)), row.names = c(241L, 242L, 243L, 244L), class = "data.frame")


# Convert fish dataframe to SpatialPointsDataFrame and use it with leaflet
xy <- fish[,c(2,3)] 
fish2 <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = xy, data = fish,
                                proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 
     +no_defs"))

leaflet() %>%  addTiles %>% addCircles(data = fish2,~ long,~ lat,color = "red",
                                       radius = 400,stroke = FALSE,fillOpacity = 0.9,group = "fish")  %>%
  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("fish"),
                   baseGroups = c("Esri.WorldImagery","OpenStreetMap"),position="topleft",
                   options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. You put some latitude and longitude that works with my example, however, how can I make this work with my current coordinates(long and lat)?

Comment: One way is to convert the coordinates before adding them; to be able to answer, we need your reference system. Then, look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45263/converting-geographic-coordinate-system-in-r

Comment: I have edited my answer, adding the reprojection, using a random source projection; you need to replace CRS("+proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84") by the correct Coordinate Reference System, using the proj4 string found at https://spatialreference.org/

Comment: Isn't this referencing fish2? fish2 <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = xy, data = fish,proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

Comment: About "Isn't this referencing fish2": -1110643.625 is certainly not a longitude in degrees.

Comment: I am getting this error: Error in coordinates(d_wgs84)$lon : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Replace coordinates(d_wgs84)$lon by coordinates(d_wgs84)[,"lon"]. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to help me with this dataset. It works great  now!!!

Comment: @mayeulk please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474422/in-r-leaflet-dont-reflect-the-latitude-nor-longitude?__=976320040

Comment: @Salvador Then, I guess you should accept my answer and upvote it; thanks.

Comment: @mayeulk I have accepted your answer (see the check mark above)